# DotnetFramework runtimes + SDKs installed but VS2022 & Win10 don't recognize them

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio-2022

Found either a bug in windows 10 or a bug in VS2022 or both whereby the DotNetFramework Dev tools and runtimes are installed, yet they do not show up from the command line prompt nor in Programs & Features. Attempting to reinstall any of them (4.52, 4.62, 4.72, 4.82) yields an error message stating they are already installed. Like Schroedinger's Cat, they are both installed and uninstalled simultaneously.

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>dotnet --info .NET SDK:  Version:   7.0.100
> Commit:    e12b7af219
>
> Runtime Environment:  OS Name:     Windows  OS Version:  10.0.19045
> OS Platform: Windows  RID:         win10-x64  Base Path:   D:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.100\
>
> Host (useful for support):   Version: 6.0.5   Commit:  70ae3df4a6
>
> .NET SDKs installed:
> 3.1.425 [D:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 5.0.203 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 5.0.214 [D:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 5.0.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 5.0.403 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 5.0.408 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 6.0.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 6.0.403 [D:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 7.0.100 [D:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
>
> .NET runtimes installed:   Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.28 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.30 [D:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.28 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.30 [D:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.15 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.19 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.21 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.31 [D:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.6 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.9 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.10 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.12 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.13 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.17 [D:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.5 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.11 [D:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.0 [D:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
> 2.1.28 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.30 [D:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
> 3.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.19 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
> 3.1.21 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.31 [D:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
> 5.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.9 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
> 5.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.12 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
> 5.0.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.17 [D:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
> 6.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.5 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
> 6.0.11 [D:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.0 [D:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
> Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.15 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
> Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.19 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
> Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.21 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
> Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.31 [D:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
> Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.6 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
> Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.9 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
> Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.10 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
> Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.12 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
> Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.13 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
> Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.17 [D:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
> Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.4 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
> Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.5 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
> Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.11 [D:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
> Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 7.0.0 [D:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
>
> To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:
> https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Only DotNet Core SDKs and runtimes are displayed, but none of the older DotNetFrameworks (of any version), even though they're installed.
I'm at loss and about to blow the machine away and completely start from scratch, but, would rather not.
Any ideas? (I've tried MS's "fix dotnet" tool, but that achieved nothing)

---

Looks like VS2022 is corrupted after their latest update - I attempted to Repair the installation and got
"Sorry, something went wrong"
Couldn't repair Microsoft.Net.4.8.FullRedist.20H2

There was an option to report the problem to MS, so I did.

I still believe this is a path problem (VS2022 was installed on D:\ drive and VS2019 - which had been removed a few months ago - was installed on the C:\ drive), so I may have to uninstall VS2022 and reinstall to the c:\ drive back.

Answer (score 1):

The `dotnet` tool only works for things related to ".NET" (or previously ".NET Core"), it doesn't do anything for ".NET Framework".  ".NET Framework" is a Windows component, you can't not have it installed.

As for Visual Studio, depending on the type of project you create, it will either be for .NET Framework or for .NET, but not both – unless you manually edit the project file. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71607653/25071) as an example of the different project types.

If you are still having problems, posting further details on what you're specifically trying to accomplish will help.

Comment: I'm aware of how to select the correct project type. Therein lies the rub. any framework above 3.5 is not accessible in VS2022 anymore.

Comment: DNFW, NOT Core, is the issue.  Occasionally, I have to load and update a DNF 4.72 application, but now I cannot. It broke sometime between today and 2 months ago, so it could be anything. It could be a path problem (note some have a D: drive letter due to space issues on the C: drive).  I think I need to re-partition the c: drive, uninstall VS and all dependencies, and reinstall everything. UGH

Answer (score 0):

I did some more research and the problem did lie with the path as I had suspected. I had installed VS2022 on the D:\ drive (identical path except the drive letter) due to drive space concerns.
VS was still looking in the **C:** drive, so I went to **C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework** and copied the files in the **.NETFramework** folder over to **D:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework** folder (including the folder), and now VS can see the files.  Interestingly VS2019, when installed on an alternate drive letter, correctly identifies the path.  Old projects load just fine now and the other .NET frameworks show up in the framework dropdowns, both for new projects window and the project settings window.
SOLVED!